# Need to monitor a process

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a vb script to monitor a process. The script monitors the status of a process and if the process is not running since 10 mins it should execute a command.Below is my script:

```
    set objWMIService = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
    foundProc = False
    procName = "calc.exe"

    Dim wshell

    ' Initialise the shell object to return the value to the monitor
    Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    if err.number <> 0 then
                    WScript.Echo "Error: could not create WScript.Shell (error " & err.number & ", " & err.Description & ")"
                    WScript.quit(255)
    end if

    for each Process in objWMIService.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
        If StrComp(Process.Name,procName,vbTextCompare) = 0 then
            foundProc = True
            procID = Process.ProcessId
        End If
    Next

 #####code to check the proces status   

    If foundProc = True Then
        WScript.Quit(0)


    Else

        WScript.sleep(1*60*1000)
        If foundProc = True Then
        WScript.Echo "Found Process (" & procID & ")"
        Else
            WScript.Echo "Process not running since 10 mins"
            WScript.Quit(0)

        End If

    End If
```

Comment: I am having query like if i execute the script and if suppose the process stops after a minute script eexcutes. The next iteration will check the status after 10 minutes. SO the gap of 9 minutes is huge. I need to monitor it continuosly and it should fire the command after 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace")

Do

    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    If objReceivedEvent.ProcessName = "svchost.exe" then msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
'   msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
Loop
```

You also have `Win32_ProcessTraceStart` and `Win32_ProcessTraceStop`. Above code is both.

It is also pointless doing error checking on WScript.Shell. It's a system component - it should be available. Also if it's not your script won't run as wscript isn't available to run your script.